# Strategies to collect analytics and error in windows 8 metro app

Tags: logging, error-handling, microsoft-metro, analytics, winjs

I have build a metro app using javascript, I have written around 6000 lines of codes.

I am ooking for ways to collect 2 things

1. What users is doing, user action analytics
2. Error that users may be facing, collecting a log file or some other strategy.

What are the available options and what are the available strategies to do that.

Comment: There's statistics on user javascript errors in the Windows Store backend. Not sure what level of detail it provides, though, but it will provide some details at least..

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using a cloud connection so that it was easy to see usage in a centralized location. I would create a collection of log messages, analytic points, errors, etc. in the users local storage and then fire off an asynchronous service at application launch (and perhaps every few minute thereafter) that made sure the user was connected to the internet, and then I would push records from the local storage into an Azure Mobile Service.
If you haven't set up Azure Mobile Services before, they're super easy, cheap, and handy. You can just create a table to store the data points and add an extra property for the user's receipt ID (that uniquely identifies them and their machine). Now you've always got one table for usage data for all of your users.
That's my $0.02.